# Python, Regular Expression Postcode search

Tags: python, regex, postal-code

I am trying to use regular expressions to find a UK postcode within a string.

I have got the regular expression working inside RegexBuddy, see below:

```
\b[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9][A-Z0-9]? [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}\b
```

I have a bunch of addresses and want to grab the postcode from them, example below:

> 123 Some Road Name
>  Town, City
>  County
>  PA23 6NH

How would I go about this in Python?  I am aware of the `re` module for Python but I am struggling to get it working.

Cheers

Eef

Comment: You should check: http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/gdsc/schemas/bs7666-v2-0.xsd

Especially "(GIR 0AA)|((([A-Z-[QVX]][0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-Z-[QVX]][A-Z-[IJZ]][0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-Z-[QVX]][0-9][A-HJKSTUW])|([A-Z-[QVX]][A-Z-[IJZ]][0-9][ABEHMNPRVWXY])))) [0-9][A-Z-[CIKMOV]]{2})" for a standard regex

Answer (score 10, accepted):

repeating your address 3 times with postcode PA23 6NH, PA2 6NH and PA2Q 6NH as test for you pattern and using the regex from wikipedia against yours, the code is..

```
import re

s="123 Some Road Name\nTown, City\nCounty\nPA23 6NH\n123 Some Road Name\nTown, City"\
    "County\nPA2 6NH\n123 Some Road Name\nTown, City\nCounty\nPA2Q 6NH"

#custom                                                                                                                                               
print re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9][A-Z0-9]? [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}\b', s)

#regex from #http://en.wikipedia.orgwikiUK_postcodes#Validation                                                                                            
print re.findall(r'[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9R][0-9A-Z]? [0-9][A-Z]{2}', s)
```

the result is

```
['PA23 6NH', 'PA2 6NH', 'PA2Q 6NH']
['PA23 6NH', 'PA2 6NH', 'PA2Q 6NH']
```

both the regex's give the same result.

Comment: Since I value clarity I'd modify the regex to be: '[A-Z]{1,2}[\dR][\dA-Z]? \d[A-Z]{2}'
(\d instead of [0-9], if you mean "a digit", better say so directly.)

Comment: Actually i just took the regex "as-is" from the question. Since the question was on using re module in python and not on regex specifically, I decided against tinkering with the regex in question.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import re
re.findall("[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9][A-Z0-9]? [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}", x)
```

You don't need the \b.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

ADDRESS="""123 Some Road Name
Town, City
County
PA23 6NH"""

reobj = re.compile(r'(\b[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9][A-Z0-9]? [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}\b)')
matchobj = reobj.search(ADDRESS)
if matchobj:
    print matchobj.group(1)
```

Example output:

```
[user@host]$ python uk_postcode.py 
PA23 6NH
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for postcodes like PA236NH, PA2Q6NH, pa23 6nh, pa2q6NH

```
def get_postcode(text):
    # get all words with leading and ending digits along with atleast one alphabet

    pattern = r'\b[a-zA-Z]+\d+[a-zA-Z]?\b|\b\d+[a-zA-Z]+\b'    
    postcode = re.findall(pattern,  text.strip()) 

    # there may be postcodes expressed without a blank space
    if len(postcode) < 2:
          # extract all words with minimum 2 digits
          postcode = re.findall(r'\b[a-zA-Z]+\d+[a-zA-Z]?\d+[a-zA-Z]+\b', text.strip())

    postcode = ' '.join(postcode)
    return postcode
```